# Android ArcGIS - displaying a popup window when marker is touched

Tags: android, gis, android-mapview, geospatial, arcgis

Does anyone know how, if possible, to display a popup infoWindow type bubble when a marker is tapped on an **ArcGIS MapView** in an Android app?

I've managed to create a SimpleMarkerSymbol type marker but I would like to be able to display more information about the marker when the user presses on it, not sure if this is even possible in ArcGIS. Thanks
code for **map** and **marker**:

```
GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.addLayer(graphicsLayer);
SimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED, 10, SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.CROSS);
Point pointGeometry = new Point(34.056215, -117.195668);
Graphic pointGraphic = new Graphic(pointGeometry, simpleMarker);
graphicsLayer.addGraphic(pointGraphic);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three things you need to accomplish:

1. Listen for the user's tap. This is done by adding an [`OnSingleTapListener`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/event/OnSingleTapListener.html) to the [`MapView`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html).
2. Query the graphics for the point the user tapped. You can use [`GraphicsLayer.getGraphicIds(float, float, int, int)`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/GraphicsLayer.html) to query the graphics.
3. Display the popup. This is done by calling [`MapView.getCallout().show(Point, View)`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/Callout.html).

Check out a really awesome example of [an `OnSingleTapListener` that does #2 and #3](https://github.com/garys-esri/offline-mapper-android/blob/master/source/OfflineMapper/app/src/main/java/com/esri/wdc/offlinemapper/controller/IdentifyListener.java). At least I think it's awesome because I wrote it. ;-)

Comment: Hero! After hours of searching the web for if you were able to create popup infoWindows using ArcGIS for Android, I couldn't find a thing. I thought I was going to have to use Google maps! Thank you :)

Comment: I'll accept as answer as soon as I get something working

Comment: @PaulAlexander, did you figure it out?

Comment: @Shaul, if you'd like to submit a pull request that does something better, that would be great.

Comment: @GaryS. :) i was joking. your 'if' statements are opposite, harder to read in my opinion

Comment: Ah, okay. Harder to read, but also harder to make an assignment instead of a comparison in C or JavaScript or pretty much anything except Java. #habit